# two forms, two inputs...but only one output with Javascript + web3

Tags: javascript, jquery

The project is to change someone's name, and I have two forms for two names.
I can never change the name in the second form.
I was asked to come here instead of posting in the ethereum section 
When I run the code in solidity, I can change the names, no problem.
When I run it with ganache, no dice, so I assume it is a javascript problem.

solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract Election {
    string public candidateName;
    string public candidateotherName;
   
    

    function Election () public {
        candidateName = "Candidate 1";
        candidateotherName = "Candidate2";
    }

    function setCandidate (string _name) public {
       
       candidateName = _name;
    }
    
    
     function setOtherCandidate (string _othername) public {
     candidateotherName = _othername;
     
}
}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
          <div id="content">
            <h4 id="candidateName"></h4>

            <form id="form">

                <div class="input-group">
                  <input  name="candidateName">
                  </input>

                    <button type="submit" >Add Candidate</button>

                </div>
              </div>
            </form>


            <div id="othercontent">
              <h4 id="candidateotherName"></h4>

              <form id="form1" >

                  <div class="input-group">
                    <input name="candidateotherName"  id='testid'>
                    </input>
                      <button type="submit" >Add other Candidate</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </form>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/web3.min.js"></script>
    <script>

      if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
      } else {
        web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545'));
      }

          web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];


      var contractAbi = [I know i put in the ABI here, i'm just leaving it blank];


      var contractAddress = 'I know i have to put in the address here, I am leaving it blank';


      var contract = web3.eth.contract(contractAbi).at(contractAddress);


      contract.candidateName(function(err, candidateName) {
        $('#candidateName').html(candidateName);
      });


      contract.candidateotherName(function(err, candidateotherName) {
        $('#candidateotherName').html(candidateotherName);
      });


      $('form').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        contract.setCandidate($('input').val());
      })

      $('form1').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        contract.setOtherCandidate($('testid').val());
      })


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried changing

```
contract.setOtherCandidate($('testid').val());
```

to

```
contract.setOtherCandidate($('input').val());
```

and changing the input type,changing the names for all the variables, and trying something
where i reference the id's using #. 
I cannot get the second form to update on submission and I do not know why, but remain convinced it is due to the line  near the bottom where "testid" needs to be changed to something else. I am also a javascript noob. Can I not have two inputs on the same page? 
I have looked at a lot of forums with a similar issue, but what i have tried has not worked.

Comment: contract.setOtherCandidate($('#input').val()); try this one, # is selector for id and . is selector for class, 
$("[Selector]SelectorName")

Comment: I appreciate the help, but no dice. I also tried `contract.setOtherCandidate($('#testid').val()); `for the id (called "testid" in form 2), as well as giving the second form a class named "otherinput" and trying `contract.setOtherCandidate($('.otherinput').val());`

Comment: It worked once I made every name unique for each "form section" (unique header, form names, id...) and then referenced those.
I also used # to reference id's as @trixo suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT

It works once I rewrote it as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>

            <h4 id="candidateName"></h4>

            <form id="form">


                  <input  id="nameone" name="candidate1Name">
                  </input>

                    <button type="submit" >Add Candidate</button>



            </form>

            <h5 id="othercandidateName"></h5>

            <form id="otherform">


                  <input  id="othernameone" name="othercandidate1Name">
                  </input>

                    <button type="submit" >Add Candidate</button>



            </form>



    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/web3.min.js"></script>
    <script>

      if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
      } else {
        web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545'));
      }

          web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];


      var contractAbi =[my way cool ABI]
;


      var contractAddress = 'my way cool address';


      var contract = web3.eth.contract(contractAbi).at(contractAddress);


      contract.candidateName(function(err, candidateName) {
        $('#candidateName').html(candidateName);
      });



      $('#form').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        contract.setCandidate($('#nameone').val());
      })

      contract.othercandidateName(function(err, othercandidateName) {
        $('#othercandidateName').html(othercandidateName);
      });


            $('#otherform').on('submit', function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              contract.othersetCandidate($('#othernameone').val());
            })

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I made every name unique for each "form section" (unique header, form names, id...) and then referenced those.
I also used # to reference id's as @trixo suggested